# Check Box value post based checked or unchecked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I am using two page in my project one page  **calculate.php** and another page name defaults **results.php**

calculate page i have called input page . i have checkbox looks like

```
<div class="col-md-2  padding-Zero">
    <input name="upfrontMIPPc" id="upfrontMIPPc1" type="text" class="txt" size="3" maxlength="3" onChange="javascript:upfrontMIPPcChanged(true)" />      
    <input type="text" name="upfrontmipamt" id="upfrontmipamt" class="txt" size="7"
  onChange="javascript:upfrontMIPAmountChanged(true)" maxlength="7"/>
  </div>

<div class="col-md-1 padding-lft">
    <img id="upfront1" src="Content/Images/percent.png" onclick="changeupfront1(event,this.src)" style="cursor:pointer;margin-left:2px"/>
</div>

<div class="col-md-1 padding-lft" style="right:13px;top:3px">
    <input id="chkUFtoLoan-1" type="checkbox" /> 
</div>
```

My question  if the user checked the Include In Calc button from the input page.  They should all be defaulted to checked (as we are defaulting to adding the UPFRONT MIP balance to the loan).  But if they uncheck the checkboxes, then the value gets placed in the Buyer Costs To Close Section.

they value post depends user check box selection this value post another page defaults results page

**About your Loan:**

```
<div class="result-header">
    <p>About Your Loan</p>
</div>

<div class="row content black">
    <label id="Label20"  class="pull-left">Financed Upfront MIP</label>
    <label id="ss_financedmip"  class="pull-right">$<?php echo round($arrSecondBox["ssupfrontmipamt"],2);?></label>

</div>
```

**Buyer close to section**

```
<div class="result-header">
    <p>Buyer Cost To Close</p>
</div>    

<div class="row content green">
     <label id="Label152" for="purchasePrice" class="pull-left ">Upfront MIP Financed</label>
     <label id="ss_financedmip"  class="pull-right">$<?php echo round($arrSecondBox["ssupfrontmipamt"],2);?></label>
</div>
```

if the user checked the Include In Calc button from the input page.  They should all be defaulted to checked (as we are defaulting to adding the UPFRONT MIP balance to the loan).  But if they uncheck the checkboxes, then the value gets placed in the Buyer Costs To Close Section?

MY script for checkbox or uncheck box:

```
$('input[Name="S"]').mouseenter(function() { 
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).prop('checked',false);
      //  alert("is checked");
    } else {
         $(this).prop('checked',true);
       // alert("not checked");
    }
});
</script>
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2dgp0drd)

please give any idea about it? thanks in advance .

Comment: You left out a valuable piece of code... the javascript.

Comment: My written code its Not Working

Comment: We need to see the javascript code as well

Comment: wait i  will post my script @Kuya

Comment: please take look my script  S  value  get from checkbox name i   am post the S value input page to results page

Comment: nope...requirement is pretty unclear...can you provide a fiddle???

Comment: wait i will give link

Comment: @NoobEditor  please take look my link if user click check value 100 add  about your loan  and if uncheck value add to buyer to close   my Link  https://jsfiddle.net/2dgp0drd/

Comment: @samyNathanP : you mean, you need to show / hide depending on the "check" status?